# sql 2012 varchar to date format conversion

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am using SQL Server 2012 and have a table that contains a column **Orderdate** with dates in the `varchar(8)` format like **28082015**. I need to convert this date to Date (ddmmyyyy) in date format 103 and have created a new column for that.

```
SELECT  
       [Custid]
      ,[orderdate],....
      ,[newcol]

FROM mytable
```

How do I convert and update the date in new column (newcol) I created in date format.

Comment: http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/

Comment: Why not just store them as `DateTime` originally?

Answer (score 0):

Try with the below query.

```
UPDATE t
SET newcol=CONVERT(datetime,LEFT (Orderdate,2)+'-'+SUBSTRING(Orderdate,3,2)+'-'+ RIGHT(Orderdate,4) ,103)
FROM mytable t
WHERE ISNULL(t.Orderdate,'')!=''
```

or use a `STUFF` function .

```
UPDATE t
SET newcol=CONVERT(datetime,STUFF(STUFF(Orderdate,3,0,'-'),6,0,'-'),103)
FROM mytable t
WHERE ISNULL(t.Orderdate,'')!=''
```

Comment: tried this but getting following erro...r  Msg 242, Level 16, State 3, Line 7
The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.
The statement has been terminated.

Comment: are you sure the column orderdate contains date in the format DDMMYYYY? i

Comment: does the column allows NULL or blank space?

Comment: there is one null record, yes.

Comment: Have you tried with the updated script?

Comment: Its working fine now....greatful for your help..

Comment: Mark it as right answer, if you agree with this solution..

Answer (score 0):

-- truncate table #RobTemp
    create table #RobTemp (DateIn Varchar(8))

```
insert into #RobTemp (DateIn) Values ('10202018')
insert into #RobTemp (DateIn) Values (null)
insert into #RobTemp (DateIn) Values ('02302016')

select case isdate(convert(DateTime, substring(DateIn,1,2) + '/' + substring(DateIn,3,2) + '/' + substring(DateIn,5,4) )) 
             when 1 then convert(DateTime, substring(DateIn,1,2) + '/' + substring(DateIn,3,2) + '/' + substring(DateIn,5,4) ) 
             else null end 
from #RobTemp
```

Comment: I think you have to cover for when it is a valid date, when it is not a valid date and when it is null.  I think this covers it for you.......